# Header pull based on three column values

Tags: indexing, excel-formula, match

I have an awkward set up for client tables, and I need to pull the start month from Table 2 into Table 1 (need cell A3 to be Nov, A4 to be Dec).

In order to do so I need to match the client name, service = start, and month cell = 1.

I've tried various versions of index matching, with column searches, max, sumproduct, arrays, and cannot figure it out.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

[image: Example Table]

Comment: what version of Excel do you have?  Simple with Office 365 dynamic array formula.  A little harder with other versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Office 365 dynamic array formula:

```
=INDEX($G$2:$J$2,MATCH(1,FILTER($G$3:$J$7,($E$3:$E$7=B3)*($F$3:$F$7="Start")),0))
```

[image]

In older versions:

```
=INDEX($G$2:$J$2,MATCH(1,INDEX($G:$J,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($F$3:$F$7)/(($E$3:$E$7=B3)*($F$3:$F$7="Start")),1),0),0)))
```

[image]